# RPC call Weblogic 10.3 and Axis 1.4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, axis

I am trying to make a RPC method call via Axis 1.4 over weblogic 10.3. Bu I always having following error.

```
org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: No Service named SendMessagePort is available
```

When I have used exactly same code portion in Java SE project, there is no error occurred.

Link http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/install.html indicated that there should be an additional configuration when using weblogic 8.1 and axis 1.4. Although I have applied this method it has not solved the issue.

I am sure that .wsdl is accessible and can make a call using SOAP UI.

Is there a similar configuration for weblogic 10.3 to create Axis client and make rpc call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modifying startWebLogic.cmd as following. Problem is resolved.

```
set CLASSPATH=%SAVE_CLASSPATH%;%DOMAIN_HOME%\lib\jaxrpc.jar;%DOMAIN_HOME%\lib\saaj.jar
```

After then I have realized that there is an exception occurred though everything working fine.

```
•org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: No service named XXX is available
```

This is logged because this code in AxisEngine (line 308 in Axis 1.x):

```
 public SOAPService getService(String name) throws AxisFault
    {
        try {
            return config.getService(new QName(null, name));
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            try {
                return config.getServiceByNamespaceURI(name);
            } catch (ConfigurationException e1) {
                throw new AxisFault(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

depends on an exception being thrown on the first attempt (line 311) to then try a different method of finding the service (which succeeds if you see no log of the AxisFault on line 316). The log entry is created because a ConfigurationException logs itself (at DEBUG level) on creation (questionable practice, imho). To avoid this misleading log entry you'll want to add this to your

```
log4j.properties file: 
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException = INFO
```